# Solving for $y$ for a Differential equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am trying to solve the following equation for $y$, and it is a little tricky.
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y-2)=\ln(x+3)+c$$

I'm not sure if what I have done is correct or not; thanks for the help.

$$-\left(\ln \sqrt y + \ln\sqrt {y-2}\right)=\ln(x+3)+c$$
$$-\left(\ln \sqrt {y(y-2)}\right)=\ln(x+3)+c$$
$$e^{-\left(\ln \sqrt {y(y-2)}\right)}=e^{\ln(x+3)}\cdot e^c$$
$$\left(-\sqrt {y(y-2)}\right)^2=((x+3) \cdot e^c)^2$$
$$y^2-2y=(x+3)^2 \cdot e^{2c}$$
$$y^2-2y-(x+3)^2 \cdot e^{2c}=0$$

Then applying the quadratic formula to the above second degree polynomial yields

$$y=\frac{2\pm\sqrt {4-2e^{2c}(x+3)^2}}{2}$$

Comment: What is the differential equation you are trying to solve ? I see no $y'$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Comment: I already solved the differential equation, and this is what I got. I should edit the title since the differential equation isn't involved

Comment: The step you take from the third to the fourth line is incorrect

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor what did I do wrong?

Comment: -ln x\neq ln(-x)

Answer (score 1):

$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(y-2)=\ln(x+3)+c$$ Multiplying both parts by -2, we get $$ln(y(y-2))=-2\ln(x+3)+c=ln(x+3)^{-2}+c$$ Now applying exponent, we obtain
$$y^2-2y=\frac{e^c}{(x+3)^2}$$ Thus, $$y=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4+\frac{4e^c}{(x+3)^2}}}{2}=1\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{e^c}{(x+3)^2}}$$

Comment: thanks for your answer, where did I go wrong?

Comment: you square negative number which is not safe: $(-1)^2=1^2$ does not mean that $-1=1$